# ASP.NET 2010 Exposing custom class methods to a web service client

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, class

I've seen a few postings about this topic but it hasn't helped me resolve my issue.  I have a very simple ASP.NET 2010 Web service but I'm unable to get to methods in my custom classes from my client application.  Below is my Web Service (stripped down).

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Args
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function ProcessArgs(Args As Arguments) As String
        Return Args.Items(0).Value
    End Function
End Class
```

This is my custom class

```
Public Class Arguments
    Public Items() As Argument

    Public Class Argument
        Public Name As String
        Public Value As String
    End Class

    Public Function Count() As Long
        Return Items.Count
    End Function

    Public Function Add(Name As String, Value As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim lngIndex As Long = 0
            Dim newArg As New Argument

            newArg.Name = Name
            newArg.Value = Value

            If Not Items Is Nothing Then lngIndex = Items.Count
            ReDim Preserve Items(lngIndex)
            Items(Items.Count() - 1) = New Argument
            Items(Items.Count() - 1) = newArg
            Return 0

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

I add the web reference to my client application. My client code is:

```
Dim args As New csWSArgs.Arguments
```

I can't access the Add(...) method or the Count() property.  I tried adding the  _ but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper methods in your WebService and from them call methods of internal class, but I think you have a bigger problem.

Web Service by nature is stateless. You call it, it perform some operation, return result if any and that's it. It looks like objects created from your internal class are meant to stay in memory and accumulate elements in `Items` array. This is not going to work with WebService approach, perhaps you need to rethink your design.